# If I replay WoL campaign and make different chooses, would it change HotS campaign a bit? [minor spoiler]

Tags: starcraft-2

During one of the early missions in Heart of the Swarm,

> Nova mentioned about how I helped Tosh instead of helping her,

back in WoL.

I wonder if that's just some scripted lines she say no matter what, or is it dynamically changing. Have you heard of her saying the opposite?

Would replaying Wings of Liberty make any difference?

Comment: @Sterno The linked question has no accepted answer, so I am unable to close this question.

Comment: @deutschZuid There are ways, but they involve [trickery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166227/178007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is indeed based on the decision you've made during the WOL campaign. For me it's been the exact opposite.

> She talked to Jim about how he helped her (I did the Nova missions back then).

I think the actual scene playing is still the same (just changed text/voiceover).

I think (although I'm not 100% sure) it picks the line based on your last campaign playthrough you did before (re-)starting the HOTS campaign.